# Injective dimension is locally finite but not globally

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring. Could someone provide me an example where $\operatorname{id}_{A_{\mathfrak p}}(M_{\mathfrak p})$ is finite for all $\mathfrak p\in \operatorname{Spec}(A)$, but $\operatorname{id}_A(M)$ is infinite? (Here $M$ is an $A$-module and $\operatorname{id}_A(M)$ stands for its injective dimension.)

We know that this does not happen with projective dimension.

Comment: This $can$ happen with projective dimension.  See the following: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274818/does-finite-projective-dimension-localize

Comment: Also, I think that, when $R$ isn't Noetherian, it is possible for a module over $R$ to be locally injective but not globally injective.  Of course, there is no guarantee such a module would have infinite injective dimension $a$ $priori$, but this could be a source of examples to take a look at.

Answer (score 2):

If change everywhere "projective" by "injective" in my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274818/does-finite-projective-dimension-localize), then you can find such an example.